# My website doesnt redirect me to the page i want it to redirect javascript, expressjs, passportjs

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

https://github.com/LapaJr31/somerandomprojects/blob/main/server.js -- full code
https://youtu.be/1tH0meEmfqE -- recording of process

Here is a piece of code that must redirect me to the page after log in but it doesnt.

```
app.post('/login', checkNOTauthenticated ,  passport.authenticate('local', {
    
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failireFlash: true   
}))
```

There is no errors. I think it just implements failureRedirect all the time

Comment: My guess is that you haven't told passport where to find your password and how to decrypt it. Not sure how to do it, but I checked your "full code"-link and couldn't find any password information except when you create the user. And you've misspelled `failureFlash` as `failireFlash`.

Comment: So, taking a guess if you are getting authenticated just fine(session is started and all) then, you should check your index route and its corresponding  ejs file. Else plz check whether you are getting authenticated , you can try to do so by using devtools whether session is being created or not, if not then there should be a problem from passport side in fetching your credentials.